# Pressure-force limiting blocks or relief mechanism for avoiding excessive pressure over a piece

Tags: applied-mechanics

I am looking for some device that can be used for blocking a sheet of glass or other materials in position. On one side of the glass (blue sheet in the diagram) is applied a force if the force is above a certian value the upper block is released and the glass is free to move upward.

[image]

I am looking for a kind of force limiting relief device but I can't find anything already on the market? Am I missing something? Is there any conventional name for such devices?

Answer (score 3):

Hold the top block in place with a spring loaded ball mechanism.

Check out cupboard latches or spring loaded latches as an example.

Also known as ball and detent...

Comment: Seems a good starting point but is there anything I can use to regulate the pressure?

Comment: Yes, the depth of the detent and the strength of the spring.

Comment: Ok, thanks I was looking for something I could regulate for different pieces but it is a good starting point. The main drawback is that I need to perform a dent on the glass.

Comment: Why not between the top support and its frame?

Comment: You are right that make sense I was not thinking them as two separate entities but I could do something like that.